# Does any sql server database have a GUID that is different than its display name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I want to take a backup of our SQL server 2008 R2 live database , and then restore it inside our dev SQL server.
I am using SQL server 2008 R2 management studio to do the backup and restore, AS FOLLOW:-

- I open the live server DB, right click on it , Tasks >>Backup.
- this generate a file named live.bak.
- then inside my Dev DB I create a new DB, I name it "TestDB".
- I right click on it , Tasks >> Restore.
- now I have restored a live copy of the DB inside the Dev.

Now the database on dev, have its name  = `TestDB`,, but does any database have a GUID which might be different than its name ? my question is that I need to confirm that our live & test db did not get the same GUID or the same name?
 can anyone advice on this? does sql server have a guid ?

Comment: What do you mean by a GUID which is different than its name? I don't understand that question. And yes sql server has a guid. It is called uniqueidentifier. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange now I run this "select * from sys.databases" and can find this column service_broker_guid is this the database guid or id ?

Comment: Databases don't have "GUID" in the manner I think you're asking. It does have a database id for system reasons, but it's not unique across different servers as a databases aren't handled in that manner. If you're restoring a database on a different server/instance, the database naming and ID on another server/instance is completely irrelevant to the original.

Answer (score 1):

run below query

```
select * from sys.databases
```

it shows all the information for a database. there is no unique information for database but name and database_id

BTW, I don't know why you are concern about it!

Comment: so the guid is the service_broker_guid?

Comment: @JohnJohn, Server_broker_guid is the guid for service broker service. I think you can get the right answer, if you say what you asked the question and what are you trying for find.

Comment: I am trying to find the database id or guid ??

Comment: @JohnJohn, using my query you get the database id which is the identifier for each database. So is my answer what you are looking for? if so, please mark it as answer. thanks

Comment: `sys.databases` described: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This query returns the GUID you need, for the current Database.

```
SELECT database_guid 
FROM sys.database_recovery_status
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()
```

Of course the user can always rename his database after this GUID.